# Custom Validator not displaying error message in the form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

The solutions I sought out do not solve my problem. I wrote a custom validator to force user to fill a field depending on a enum value selected from a dropdown. But the error message does not display when the required field is empty. When the select is Farmer (enum field) Outreach Person must be selected from dropdown (OutreachPersonId).

**Custom Validator**

```
    public class RequiredOutreachOfficerAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private CardTypes _cardTypes;

        public RequiredOutreachOfficerAttribute(CardTypes cardTypes)
        {
            _cardTypes = cardTypes;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            CreateBusinessPartnerVM businessPartner = (CreateBusinessPartnerVM)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

            if (businessPartner.CardType == _cardTypes && !businessPartner.OutreachPersonId.HasValue)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("A farmer must have an outreach officer");
            }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
[RequiredOutreachOfficer(CardTypes.Farmer, ErrorMessage = "A farmer must have an outreach officer")]
public Guid? OutreachPersonId { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<label asp-for="OutreachPersonId">Outreach Officer</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OutreachPersonId, Model.OutreachPersons, "", new { @id = "drpOutreachPersonId", @class = "browser-default" })
 <span asp-validation-for="OutreachPersonId" class="text-danger"></span>
```

It seems that the custom validator works because when I select a "Farmer" enum from the dropdown, and I submit the page, it throws an exception;

> InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type
>   'IEnumerable' that has the key 'OutreachPersonId'.

But when I select another input that is not "Farmer" the page submits successfully. But I need the validation message to show. Please help.

Comment: You do not get any client side validation because your attribute does not implement `IClientValidatable` and you have not included scripts to add the rules to the `$.validator`. Once you repopulate `OutreachPersons` as described in the dupe, your error message will be displayed

Comment: If you want client side validation, then refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)